# Var1 created while conversion from table to dataframe does not work when used in .R reusable script

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

I have a categorical (factor variable) Age with diff age groups
I am creating a bar chart follows. (all libraries loaded)

```
tl=table(df$Age)
df1=as.data.frame(tl)
p=ggplot(data = df1,mapping = aes(x = Var1, y = Freq))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
p=p+geom_text(aes(label=Freq), vjust=-0.3, size=3.5)
p=p+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
p=p+labs(y="Y", x="X",title = "Title")
```

This works when i use it on console/command prompt

But I tried to create a reusable script and created a function as follows

```
barfig_demo=function(x)
  
{
  
 
    
  library(dplyr)
  
  library(ggplot2)
    
    tl=table(x)
    df1=as.data.frame(tl)

    p=ggplot(data = df1,mapping = aes(x = Var1, y = Freq))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
    p=p+geom_text(aes(label=Freq), vjust=-0.3, size=3.5)
    p=p+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
    p=p+labs(y="x", x="y",title = "title")
    ggsave(paste0("Test",".jpg"))
    
   
    
  }
```

I pass a column df$Age to this function. When you create dataframe by using as.data.frame, the column names are Var1 and Freq.
I am getting an error  as follows

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Var1' not found
```

can someone please help

Comment: That worked !!!Could you please explain further as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `{{}}` curly-curly braces.

With the `{{` operator you can tunnel data-variables (i.e. columns from the data frames) through arg-variables (function arguments):

The tunnel makes it possible to supply variables from the data frame to your wrapper function:

See here: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/02/glue-strings-and-tidy-eval/

In your case:
Replace in your function:

```
tl=table(x)
```

with

```
tl=table({{x}})
```